# Cakephp 2.2 and SWFUploader black-holed

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, uploadify, swfupload

I am having a typical file upload method (inside a plugin) in my app and I am using for this Uploadify that uses SFWUpload.
I used this for an application that is written in CakePHP 1.3 (and it worked OK). Now I am updating the app to CakePHP 2.2.2. The problem is that when I am trying to upload the file I am getting a Security black-holed error (400 error).

- I have disabled the Security for the uploader action inside the beforeFilter() callback but no success.

> ```
> if($this->request->action == 'add_profile_picture'){
>
>    $this->Security->enabled = false;
>
> }
> ```

- I have also disabled the Auth for that function so I don't have any problems on upload regarding the passing of Session and Flash...

> ```
> ...
>     $this->Auth->allow('add_profile_picture');
> ...
> ```

If anyone had similar problems and solve it please give me a hint or two.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this flash uploader using hidden fields via post that are NOT generated by the CakePHP FormHelper? If yes you'll need to whitelist these fields in the security component to make them pass.

Comment: There are no hidden fields except the one that is generated normally by the form helper, yeah. I was deactivating the whole security component and it is working but this is just a rubbish solution...

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, 'enabled' isn't actually a property of the Security component. You can instead use the validatePost attribute to achieve the same.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
        if($this->request->action == 'your_action_name'){
           $this->Security->validatePost = false;
        }
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }
```